# recording quiet noise with AVAudioRecorder - volume changes over time - why?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I try to record a real quiet noise with AVAudioRecorder for an iPhone app.

I use these settings:
AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
AVSampleRateKey: 48000,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue

The real quiet noise is the ticking of a wrist watch, you can hardly hear it when you listen directly to the watch by holding it close to the ear. The duration of the record is just about 10s. The record of this noise starts with low volume, and the volume increases over time.
The visualisation of the record (see attached screenshot) also confirms, that the volume is low at the beginning and gets louder with the time for about the first 5s (half of the record), then it stays constant more or less. In reality the volume is constant, not increasing or decreasing.
[screenshot of visualised record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO9Tf.jpg)

Why does the volume change? Any idea? Is this something LinearPCM is doing?

I tried two other formats by only changing AVFormatIDKey to other values, but then my app crashed. I tried kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 and kAudioFormatAppleLossless.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi there
my question has nothing to do with code, but with audio formats.
When I google for "waveform images" and then I look at hundreds of pictures, they all have the same behaviour, which is not reality. All look like the recorded sound starts with volume 0 and gets louder after a few seconds. Just imagine a real scenario, you go out with your iPhone, and start recording the noise around you with the iPhone voice recorder. Looking then to the image of the noise, it looks like it started with silence, although in reality the noise was already loud when you tapped the record button. Ideas?

Comment: This seems to be some kind auto-levelling (dynamics compression) your device does. I don't know if you can avoid that when using the built in microphone.